# How to use the NOW() in this line

Tags: php, mysql

hope you're fine... first, I would like to say that English is not my first language, so I'll try to explain my problem.

I have a website for tv shows subtitles and now I'm adding a new variable in my web, where I can select the option to upload a subtitle and it will be hidden (invisible on my index).

So, I have all the variables and the rest of the programmation.

Thing is that when I'm trying to put the variables in the same order that are in my database, I can't make it work:

For example.

If I use:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO fversions(subID,fversion,author,versionDesc,comment,hidden,indate) " .
 "VALUES(" . $subID . "," . $fversion . "," . $userID .
   ",'" . $fversions . "','" . $comment . "','" . $hidden . "',NOW())";
     mysql_query($query);
```

<

It's working... thing is that in my databse, "indate" is before "hidden"... it's indate and then hidden because is the new row.

So, I'm trying to put the values in order but I can't make it work.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO fversions(subID,fversion,author,versionDesc,comment,indate,hidden) " .
"VALUES(" . $subID . "," . $fversion . "," . $userID . ",'" . $version . "','" . $comment . ",NOW(),'" . $hidden;
                   mysql_query($query);
```

If I put indate and then hidden (just to have everything in order), it's not working because I don't know how to write that line...

I'm not developer, I lost mine, So I'm trying to do my best and I don't know how to write the values NOW() and $hidden so it could work.

NOW() is the value of indate, that is the hour (actual time).

Could anyone could write me how I need to write this sentence:

```
  "VALUES(" . $subID . "," . $fversion . "," .
       $userID . ",'" . $version . "','" . $comment . ",NOW(),'" . $hidden;
```

So it could work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whats the type of your database field that is receiving the date? You might have to format the date to the right format.

Comment: Let me explain, everything's working right now... because who created my website did everything... thing is that I'm just adding a new variable right now (that is hidden). So my only problem is that I don't know how to write that line that I wrote there (the values line). I mean, I don't have to change anything, just I need help to add the "hidden" variable that works with the NOW().

Comment: So... in other words... I just need this: $query = "INSERT INTO fversions(subID,fversion,author,versionDesc,comment,hidden,indate) " .
                "VALUES(" . $subID . "," . $fversion . "," . $userID . ",'" . $fversions . "','" . $comment . "','" . $hidden . "',NOW())";
                 mysql_query($query);< but with indate before of hidden. Where NOW() is the value of indate and $hidden is for hidden...

Comment: "INSERT INTO Table(field1,field2,field3) VALUES('$phpvar1','$phpvar2',NOW())"

Comment: whats with all the dots. PHP is mysql ready no need to write your query like that

Comment: Well, thing is that right now I don't have a developer in my website, so I can't have the pleasure to make big changes, you know xD because I don't want to break anything... that's why I posted here how's the code so someone could help me and just fix me the line using the same that I posted...

Comment: Well you cant just change the order like that. You would have to change the order of your DB as well. Plus i dont see why you need a specific order since when you retreive the data you do what you want with it

Comment: i guess missing quotes in the query : try this : -  $query = "INSERT INTO fversions(subID,fversion,author,versionDesc,comment,indate,hidden) " .
"VALUES(" . $subID . "," . $fversion . "," . $userID . ",'" . $version . "','" . $comment . "',NOW(),'" . $hidden."')";

Comment: The order in my database is indate and then hidden. I'm just saying that if I use the hidden before indate it's working because NOW() its closing the line and it just easy to add the variable before closing the line. Thing is that in my databse I'm adding the hidden row, so hidden is the last. So I would like to respect the order in the variables... and that's my only problem.. I dont know how to write the now() before the $hidden and close the line. It's just that :$

Comment: i hope u tried my above solution and that should work fine.

Comment: @shashikant kuswaha - Ok, I wil try that now... I'll let you know

Comment: Your missing quotes and have to many of them as well. There is no need to escape all your php variable like that

INSERT INTO table (fieldname) VALUES ('value');  
"INSERT INTO table (fieldname) VALUES ('$phpVar')"

Comment: MadeInDreams - I understand you, but I would like that you understand that I'm alone right now, so I can;'t change this part of the code because it will break everything else... so  it's impossible to me.

Comment: shashikant kuswaha  - thanks.... but is there any other way to put this? cause it's partially working with the order you sent me, just I feel something weird because the upload was done but to another place :$

Like I said: this one its working:

$query = "INSERT INTO fversions(subID,fversion,author,versionDesc,comment,hidden,indate) " .
 "VALUES(" . $subID . "," . $fversion . "," . $userID .
   ",'" . $fversions . "','" . $comment . "','" . $hidden . "',NOW())";
     mysql_query($query);

But I don't know if I have to respect the order in the database or not - hidden must be the last

Comment: ok , No you dont have to think about order unless you are specifying each and every column name in the there , so for your answer : No you should not be worried about your order of table columns how your insert it should work fine .

Comment: ok... because I was worried... I thought that I need to respect the order that is in the databs at the moment of writing the php.

Comment: ok , i guess your problem is solved , you can like my comment

Comment: @MadeInDreams - Could you please send me what you was saying?

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO fversions(subID,fversion,author,versionDesc,comment,hidden,indate) VALUES('$subID','$fversion' , '$userID' ,'$fversions ',' $comment ',' $hidden','NOW()')";
     mysql_query($query);

Comment: @shashikant kuswaha - Thanks a lot! I was waiting for your answer; is there's any other way to write the line but using the right order... I mean, it's working with the line you sent me, but I'm worried because the first time I tried, failed, then was working good... so I would like to know is there another way to write that? (I'm talking about the ".," and those things :$

Comment: @MadeInDreams - remember that hidden is the last... if you can edit that please :)

Comment: You are probably using  the dot technique to use the doublequote so you values can containe singlequote. The thing is that the single quote is not the apostrophne but we use it as one.

Comment: @Randy Garcia You cant change the order in an insert query like that. It  would require you to do more coding.

Comment: However you can set the result in the order you want when you retreive them and show them. As long as you have the data. We dont really care about the order.

Comment: One way ore another it requires coding.

Comment: MadeInDreams, I would like to know... do I need to have the exact order in the code as it's in my database? The order is indate and then hidden. You sent me the code with hidden first. The order doesn't matter? Like shashikant kuswaha told me or indeed matter?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last question and code.

You're going to want to move to mysqli from mysql sooner rather than later. The former will be deprecated if you update your php version.

Assuming all your php variables except $version and $comment are integers/floats:

```
VALUES(" . $subID . ", " . $fversion . ", " .
   $userID . ", '" . $version . "', '" . $comment . "', NOW(), " . $hidden . ")"
```

You could improve with sprintf():

```
sprintf("VALUES(%d, %d, %d, '%s', '%s', NOW(), %d)", [
    $subID, $fversion, $userID, $version, $comment, $hidden
]
```

You could improve further with mysqli_real_escape_string:

```
sprintf("VALUES(%d, %d, %d, '%s', '%s', NOW(), %d)", [
    (int)$subID,
    (int)$fversion,
    (int)$userID,
    mysqli_real_escape_string($dbLink, $version),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($dbLink, $comment),
    (int)$hidden
]
```

Comment: Hi @RandyGarcía - if that's solved your problem, then please click the tick on my answer to accept it as your solution.